# Multiuser environment using python,GAE,django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

My application is working fine for single user.

Now i am modifying it for multiuser.
How to approach for doing same. 
(first user will have his specific data. second user will have his own specific data.)

I am new to python, django and Google App Engine.

Regards,
darshana

Answer (score 1):

This is confusing. Could you possibly be talking of the admin as the single user?

Anyway, Django has an authentication framework that handles multiple user capabilities. [Here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) is the documentation, it provides models and views that you could readily use.

As for having specific data, you will need to create a User object for every user. If you want to add more fields, you can have say, a UserProfile class which has a One-to-One relationship to the User class and put the additional data there. All in the docs.

Goodluck.